# Getting message id of Discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to send a message with my Discord bot, but since the id of this message will help me in my next job, I need to send this id to another channel, how can I do it? or can i? thanks in advance for your answers

I tried this for catch the message but is not worked i tought bot is not a "author"

```py
@Bot.listen()
async def on_message(ctx):
        if ctx.message.author.id == "1006858614369177711":
          
            x_id = ctx.message.id
            await ctx.channel.send(f"currend id : {x_id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply await to the message inside a variable.

```
message = await ctx.channel.send(...)
```

Then you can get any property you want from that variable, like its id...